# RabbitTemplate send message to topic by route name wildcard

Tags: spring-rabbit

I use `RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` to send message to all route in topic by wildcard.

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(
        "/topic/javainuse.*",
        "{\"sender\":\"asfasf\",\"content\":\"asf\",\"type\":\"CHAT\"}");
```

But it not working, my route is `javainuse.49a56fc8-9cf7-41dd-a87d-4cb4016ddc91`not receive message. This is my rabbitMQ image:

[image]

Please help me to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way; the producer can't use a wildcard.

You can bind a queue with key `foo.*` and then sending with a key `foo.bar` or `foo.baz` will both be routed.